# Provider Class not found In ProviderRepository.php line 208

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I tried to uninstall the spatie/Geocoder Package 
https://github.com/spatie/geocoder
it from my laravel application, it pulled the package from Github but the package uninstallation was not successful.

Below is the Error that is returned by composer command

Terminal Screenshort:

[image]

Thanks In advance

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: did you try clearing your config? `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: yes run both command composer dumautoload and php artisan config:clear but gives the same error @aynber

Comment: Please share the error message in readable form - text is shared best as text. Additionally, **how** did you uninstall that package?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Issue is resolved by just follow these step. Go to your project > bootstrap->cache->config.php or packages.php remove the provider and aliases from the cached array manually.

Comment: Perfect solution, it works in such cases if any provider file doesn't found.

Comment: I have tried to delete the `vendor` directory and then run `compose install`. I worked!

Answer (score 17):

Easiest thing for me was to just delete the files in /bootstrap/cache/. Those will get regenerated automatically.

Comment: but the file apper again then error again

Comment: first remove provider and alias from app.php. and then remove /bootstrap/cache direcotry, and then again create directory cache directory in bootstrap directory. onward run composer dump-autoload.

Answer (score 15):

Ultimately, the fix that worked for me:

Delete the folder ***"vendor"***, and run `composer install` once again.

A more specific fix may have been possible, but this cleans things up nicely anyhow.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me because I had no config.php file in the bootstrap/cache folder. Still the old package aliases remain in some files but seems to make no errors.

Comment: Worked for me, seems like composer.lock not updating with lastest requires

Comment: don't know why... but this is the only working solution

Comment: I confirm, this one is the only one from this thread worked for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 9):

1. Run : `composer update`
2. Run : `composer dump-autoload`

It works for me with `Laravel 8.x`

Comment: In most of the cases like this composer update did the work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the lines below:

```
// config/app.php
'providers' => [
    '...',
    Spatie\Geocoder\GeocoderServiceProvider::class
];
// config/app.php
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Geocoder' => Spatie\Geocoder\Facades\Geocoder::class,
)
```

Run 'composer du' in your server console.

Comment: Already remove these lines from config file but not working showing same error @arthur Samarcos

Answer (score 5):

This is what sorted it for me.

I navigated to

```
project > bootstrap->cache folder.
```

There, was this file

```
packages.php
```

I deleted that.

```
rm packages.php
```

Then I ran

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Please note that, before running the above command, I tried running the following but it did not work

```
composer dump-autoload --no-dev
```

I ran the above in production.

Answer (score 2):

Use these 3 commands to fix the Error.

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
    
php artisan config:cache

php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\ServiceProvider::class` from the `config/app.php` will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the cache is not a suitable option (for me), as it seems to regenerate a new one with an error.  Another solution (above) is to modify the cache, and remove the error that way, but that didn't solve it either.

My error occurred trying to restore a non-working website version that was partially upgraded. My composer file was not valid and the requirements in it were wrong.  I removed all the conflicting requirements using the composer remove command.

But then I got the error above with the CashierServiceProvider class.  If this exists on another class for you, the solution I used might work but you will need to do this for your class.

First, commenting the Cashier Service worked for me in app\config.php got rid of the error.

```
Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class,
```

Then I installed the cashier Laravel app.

```
composer require laravel/cashier
```

Answer (score 0):

In such issues the below are the `magic-commands` recommended for `Laravel`:

```
rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dumpautoload
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```